# facebook comment count url with an '#' anchor tag?

Tags: facebook, comments

Im implementing the facebook comment count display feature on my site. And im using the facebook comment plugin iframe for this purpose. It works fine for the normal url of a page in my site.

My requirement is that i would like the 'comment count link' to direct the user to the comments section of the target page. So i tried appending a "#comments" (actually %23comments) anchor tag to my link but then facebook treats it as completely different url and it does not show the correct comment count for the page. Is there any way around this issue?

e.g http://www.kettik.com/go/Asia/China/Beijing/photos/361 (shows 1 comment)

but http://www.kettik.com/go/Asia/China/Beijing/photos/361#comment (shows 0 comment)

Comment: is there a reason that iframe must be used? This would be easy if it is done using HTML5 inline.